# Can you search a transaction by quantity?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I have been looking and I cant figure out a way to find a recent transaction by quantity. Let's say I know someone sent "x" amount of BTC but I don't know who was the sender nor the receiver, this transaction however was very recent, less than an hour ago. Can I search for transactions in the blockchain by quantity sent or received?

Something like the "recent transactions" tab on blockchain.info but a complete log of that.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 2 options that I am aware of:

1. https://www.goochain.net/
2. https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe

The first option is a web based tool that will search the block explorer of your choice. The second will take the blockchain and load it into a database which you can search for your desired criteria.

I just ran a test search on goochain with the criteria below and found 26 transactions:

From : 2016-05-03 Tue 03:00 UTC

To     : 2016-05-03 Tue 04:00 UTC

3.1 BTC ≤ Amount ≤ 3.2 BTC

Comment: Unfortunately goochain now links to CivicDapp.