# Searching The Blockchain Based on Transaction Amount and/or Date

Tags: transactions, blockchain, value, blockchain-explorer, time

I know there are a lot of services to look up if I have the wallet address or transaction ID. But, let's say I have no idea who the sender or receiver were nor a transaction ID but I know approximately or exactly the amount of bitcoin which were sent, and I know the approximate time period where the transaction was sent.

Is there a web-based service which would allow me to find matching transactions easily?

Similar to this question,
[Can you search a transaction by quantity?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44254/can-you-search-a-transaction-by-quantity)
But the transaction wasn't limited to the last few hours, the goochain site recommended there appears to no longer be a blockchain search tool, and I really would prefer an online interface.

I am amazed I can't find a service that does this online. All the main block explorers I checked don't seem to have this as an option.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use blockchair.com. One of their searchable data types is transaction outputs and they allow filtering both by time and amount (either BTC or USD): https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs#

Comment: Nice site. E.g. all possible Lazslo pizza's: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs?s=time(asc)&q=value(1000000000000),time(2010-05-18..2010-08-05) Related: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5453728.msg62286606#msg62286606